# ListView on Android - Selected row highlighted but doesn't go off

Tags: java, android, listview, boolean

I have an app that has a listview and the row is highlighted when clicked on.  The only problem is it stays highlighted.

My code is:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

    String item = dogToastDescriptions[position];

    v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_green_light));


       Toast.makeText(this, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getListView().setSelected(true);


       }
```

I realise that I need to use something like:

```
 getListView().setSelected(false);
```

but I can't figure out quite where to put it.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose White is default color of your list item, you should write a function refresh color of list:

```
public void refreshcolor(ListView listView)
{
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) 
    {
        View v = (View) listView.getChildAt(i);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

and call it in your `onListItemClick`

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

refreshcolor(yourListView);
String item = dogToastDescriptions[position];

v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_green_light));


   Toast.makeText(this, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
getListView().setSelected(true);


   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work.  Still keeping everything highlighted once clicked

Comment: may be you should remove getListView().setSelected(false); hope this help

Comment: I don't have that in there.  I put that in my question as a suggestion of something that I maybe should try